# No module named 'theblockchainapi' in pyscript

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyscript, pyodide

I have wirtten some lines in python and want to integrate them into my website. As soon as I want to use them I recieve an error-message stating that the module can't be found:

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, 
in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", 
line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 1, 
in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'theblockchainapi' )
```

The html is very basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
<title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id = "address"> <br>
       <button id="button">Verify NFT</button>
        <div id="out">none</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<py-env>
- theblockchainapi 
</py-env>
<py-script> 
from theblockchainapi import SolanaAPIResource, SolanaNetwork
</py-script>
```

Comment: I guess it is because theblockchainapi is not supported by pyodide yet

Answer (score 4):

The package **theblockchainapi** requires the SSL module. The SSL modules, along with **requests** are not supported in web browsers. This is a security limitation for all browser applications and not just PyScript.

The solution will require modifying **theblocckchainapi** package to use supported browser APIs.